# Books where the concept of smooth manifold is defined for arbitrary sets (not topological spaces)

Tags: reference-request, smooth-manifolds, book-recommendation

I am looking for books where the concept of smooth manifold is defined for arbitrary sets; i. e., books beginning with the definition of chart as a one-to-one map with open image and moving on to the definition of manifold as set endowed with a maximal atlas. [This one](http://users.uoa.gr/~evassil/DifGeom.pdf) would be perfect if didn't have so many missing pages.

Comment: Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* explains how this can be done, if it helps.

Comment: To follow up on @Cronus's suggestion: In particular, see Lemma 1.35 in my _Introduction to Smooth Manifolds_ (2nd ed.). It gives a set of conditions on a set with collection of charts that can be used as an alternative definition of a smooth manifold.

Comment: Wow. I did *non* think you might respond to this. With the risk of being somewhat inappropriate I'll add: Thank you for your book! It helped me a lot in my Master's.

Comment: @Versimo out of curiosity, why are you looking for such a book?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how one can define a smooth manifold for an arbitrary set.

When you say

> "beginning with the definition of chart as a one-to-one map with **open** image"

to speak about subsets of a set being open, we need to have a topology on that set, and then that set with a topology is exactly a topological space.

A smooth manifold $M$ is basically a topological manifold equipped with a smooth structure. For $M$ to be a smooth manifold it first needs to be a topological manifold, that is for each $x \in M$ there must exist an open set $U$ containing $x$ such that $U$ is homeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

So if we started of with some arbitrary set $A$, we need to endow it with a topology, then show that $A$ possesses the property that for each $a \in A$ there exists a open set $V$ of $A$ containing $a$ that is homeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then only once this is done can we talk about it being a smooth manifold or not.

Comment: Take a look at the reference I've posted.

Comment: Essentially one proceeds as follows: A chart on an arbitrary set $M$ is a one-to-one map $x \colon U \subseteq M \to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $x(U)$ is open. An atlas $\mathcal{A}$ on $M$ is a collection of charts such that their domains cover $M$ and if two charts $x \colon U \to \mathbb{R}^n$ and $y \colon V \to \mathbb{R}^n$ have intersecting domains, then $y \circ x^{-1}$ (which is a map between subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$) is a diffeomorphism. A smooth manifold is then defined as an ordered pair $(M, \mathcal{A}),$ where $M$ is a set and $\mathcal{A}$ is a maximal atlas.

Comment: What he refers is exactly what is done in Lemma 1.35 in Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*. One *can* define a smooth manifold without defining a topological space - the open sets he referred to where subsets of $\Bbb{R}^n$, not the manifold-to-be.